# sender channel going to retrying state, it reports SSL error AMQ9638

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

Sender channel is going to retrying state and immediately coming to running state but getting below Error in MQ error log :

```
AMQ9638: SSL communications error for channel 'XXXXXX'.

EXPLANATION:

Cause . . . . . : An unexpected SSL communications error occurred for a channel, as reported in the preceding messages. The channel is 'XXXXX';in some cases its name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'. The channel did not start.
Recovery . . . : Investigate the problem reported in the preceding
messages. Review the local and remote console logs for reports of network
errors. Correct the errors and restart the channel.
```

This issue facing frequently.

Could you please suggest probable reason for this error?

Comment: What version of MQ is the queue manager with the sender channel?  What about the receiver channel?  What error shows up on the receiver channel queue manager?  What is the running channel HBINT negotiated to?

Comment: The error says "Investigate the problem reported in the preceding messages". Please can you edit your question to also show the preceding message with the detail about the error.

Comment: Thanku for the reply. Got the solution.                                            May I know the functionality of HBINT?

Comment: @muralikrishnaeluri if you "got the solution" then please post a self answer to benefit others. HBINT is the heart beat interval, the receive timeout is based on this value.   I have seen errors at channel start where the remote end took a long time do to OCSP validation issues combined with a short HBINT. Remember to @ tag people otherwise there is no notification.

Comment: @JoshMc solution is HBINT value should be same on both reciever and sender channels. In my case, HBINT value was not matched on both sides.  So I matched HBINT value on both sides

Comment: @JoshMc I'm actually confusing how HBINT works. Can I have some clear explanation?

Comment: Can you add detail on what the HBINT was on each side to begin with and what you changed it to that resolved things?

Comment: It is not the case that HBINT needs to be the same on both ends of the channel. The channel will negotiate a value based on the two different values. What is more likely is that your negotiated HBINT was too short, and when you matched both ends, you lengthened the negotiated HBINT because now it would be the same as the defined HBINT. I second @JoshMc's request to add the details to your question.